# How do I sort an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sorting, data-structures

I am using an array to store occurrences of specific words in a text. The format of the data is word:number.
I would like to sort the array by descending number of occurrences (ie. by value).
Is there a neat way to do it? Or should I consider using a different data structure?

```
// This is how the array is filled.
var matches = ["word1", "word2", "word2", "word3", "word4", "word4", "word4"];  

var count = {};
$.each(matches, function(key, value) {
    if(!count[value])
        count[value] = 1;
    else
        count[value]++;
});
```

After the loop this is what I get and want to sort by descending values:

```
count = { 'word1':'1', 'word2':'2', 'word3':'1', 'word4':'3' };
```

What I actually want it to look like (sorted by value):

```
count = { 'word4':'3', 'word2':'2', 'word1':'1', 'word3':'1' };
```

Comment: It's not a valid object, though. Either the OP meant `["word1", "word2", ... ]` or he's lost his keys.

Comment: Sorry, comment was referring to the first line only (changed it). @Tomalak This is what I meant.

Comment: Please edit your post to more accurately reflect your scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sortmyway(data_A, data_B)
{
    return (data_A - data_B);
}
var list =[ 39, 108, 21, 55, 18, 9]
list.sort(sortmyway) //[9, 18, 21, 39, 55, 108]
```

See the [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/82VVn/).

Comment: The OP doesn't have an array, but an object.

Comment: Really? I doesn't look like an object, I still see an array, see this http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/82VVn/1/ when I alert "list[0]" it gives me "9".

Comment: @Rakesh: What in particular do you want explaining? Objects support `obj[i]` syntax. Arrays are a specific form of object. Arrays are created like `[1,2,3]` and are numerically indexed. More general objects are created with `{1:1, 2:2, 3:3}` and are indexed however you like.

Comment: @Rakesh: (Actually, in fairness, it looks like the OP did in fact _mean_ to talk about an array.)

Comment: @Rakesh: _Your_ code has an array. I said the OP didn't have one.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the output didn't have an array, I am being naive here, what difference does it make? I don't see any difference, though I can confirm the output is an object just trying to understand the actual difference.

Comment: @Rakesh: There is a great difference between `Object`s, and the specific case of `Object` that is `Array`. Read the chapter on them in your Javascript book. Anyway, now that we know the OP wanted arrays, you get a upvote. :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use some kind of tree for that instead as it already has the properties of a sorted map.